# Having to explicitly remove '.key' before setting/updating data in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuefire

I've created a Vue/Vuefire component for editing an existing Widget and saving the edits to Firebase.

There are some reactive properties on the Widgets that should *not* be saved to Firebase, like error messages and whether the Widget is currently shown. So I'm storing all the Firebase data in a `firebaseData` property:

```
Vue.component('widgetForm', {
    template: '#myWidgetFormTemplate',
    props: ['firebaseKey'],
    data: function(){
        return {
            error: '',
            isShown: false,
            firebaseData: {}
        }
    },
    methods: {
        show: function(){
            var form = this;
            form.isShown = true;
            form.$bindAsObject('firebaseData', fb.ref('/widgets').child(form.firebaseKey));
        },
        save: function(){
            var form = this;
            delete form.firebaseData['.key']; // This seems weird
            form.$firebaseRefs.firebaseData.set(form.firebaseData, function(err){
                if(err) form.error = err;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that when saving data, I always get the error `First argument  contains an invalid key (.key)`. My solution is to explicitly remove the `.key` property, as above.

This feels like a code smell. Is there a way to not have to do this?

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you could use firebase directly instead of vuefire.

```
methods: {
  show: function() {
    var form = this;
    form.isShown = true;
    fb.ref(`/widgets/${form.firebaseKey}`)
      .on('value')
      .then(snapshot => {
        form.firebaseData = snapshot.val();
      });
  },
  save: function() {
    var form = this;

    fb.ref(`/widgets/${form.firebaseKey}`).set(form.firebaseData, function(err) {
      if (err) form.error = err;
    });
  }
}
```